# Flutter ListView Builder scroll whole screen

Tags: flutter

I need help implementing a whole screen scroll using `ListView.Builder`

Problem is that currently I'm forced to add a fixed height of `300` to the parent Container.
This works fine but it is not really the behavior that I want.

With help from the comunnity I finally got it to work
I'm updating my code here so that others can see how I got it work

Is there a way to fix or am I out of options?

[image: image of the issue]

expences_page.dart

```
class ExpensesPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          /* Do not remove! */
          Expanded(child: Column(children: <Widget>[])),
          /* Do not remove! */
          Container(
            width: screenSize(context).width - Constants.minWidth,
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: Constants.containerMargin),
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Constants.containerPadding),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                TransactionsUser(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

transaction_list.dart

```
class TransactionList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<TransactionModel> transactions;

  TransactionList({Key key, this.transactions}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return Card(
              elevation: 5,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: Constants.containerMargin,
                      horizontal: Constants.containerMargin,
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(Constants.containerPadding),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        width: 1,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(8.0),
                        bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(8.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // The Amount
                    child: Text(
                      '\$${transactions[index].amount}',
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .subhead
                          .apply(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // The Title
                      Text(
                        transactions[index].title,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.apply(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                            ),
                      ),
                      // The Date
                      Text(
                        DateFormat.yMMMd().format(transactions[index].date),
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.apply(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: transactions.length,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your widget tree look like with Add Transaction Card included?

Comment: i guess you are using some `SingleChildScrollView` arent you?

Comment: yes I'am using SingleChildScrollView

Comment: tried `NestedScrollView`? the docs say: *"A scrolling view inside of which can be nested other scrolling views, with their scroll positions being intrinsically linked."*

Comment: and you could also use `CustomScrollView` where you can easily combine any single widgets together with lists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I presume you're using **SingleChildScrollView** with the combination of **Column** where it contains the ListView inside.

First you need to set ListView to occupy only the space required by setting

> shrinkWrap: true

If you wish you disable the scrollview of the list and give control to SingleChildScrollView. You need to set scroll physics in **ListView**

> physics: NeverScrollablePhysics()

Also giving the mainAxisSize to min in column sets the children to take up only required space.

You Widget tree should look like this.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          ...
          Flexible(
           //replace your ListView containing widget here
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount:5,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(title: Text("Index : $index"));
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: you should never do things like that - why? run this code and watch the log output: `child: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('header'),
      Flexible(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 1000,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            print('creating ListTile for index $index');
            return ListTile(title: Text("Index : $index"));
          },
        ),
      ),
      Text('footer'),
    ],
  ),
)`

Comment: @Jaser no, it does not work great - the `ListView.builder` used that way is pointless - see the code i posted above

Comment: I'm updating my code - then you can see why it works for me

Comment: @Jaser you should use `CustomScrollView` - that way builder builds only those items that are visible, not all of them - what if you had 10000 items in the list? if you check `ListView.builder` docs you will see: *"Creates a scrollable, linear array of widgets that are created on demand.

This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible."* - with the code from the answer all items are built

Comment: So I have updated my code - How do you suppose I should edit my code to fix the issue then the best way then?

Comment: So just change `SingleChildScrollView` to `CustomScrollView` ???

That is giving an error

Comment: `child: CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Text('header'),),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (ctx, index) {
          print('creating ListTile for index $index');
          return ListTile(title: Text("Index : $index"));
        },
        childCount: 1000,
      ),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Text('footer'),),
  ],
)
`

Comment: Should I place the CustomScrollView inside SingleChildScrollView or ???

Comment: @Jaser use the code i posted - it does not contain any `SingleChildScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't provide the parent of the ListView.builder it's kind of hard for me to give a correct answer. Basically change the Container to Column and add shrinkwrap: true to your ListView.builder.

```
Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      AddTransactionCard(),
      Column(
        children: [ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return Card(
              elevation: 5,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: Constants.containerMargin,
                      horizontal: Constants.containerMargin,
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(Constants.containerPadding),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        width: 1,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(8.0),
                        bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(8.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      '\$${transactions[index].amount}',
                      style: Theme.of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .subhead
                          .apply(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        transactions[index].title,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title.apply(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                            ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        DateFormat.yMMMd().format(transactions[index].date),
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.apply(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: transactions.length,
        )]
      ),
    ],
  );
)
```

Comment: So I need to add a `listView.Builder` inside a `ListView` ?

Comment: If you want your whole screen to scroll, then yes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ListView.builder, then must give fixed height to its Parent Container. It's how it should be. So only thing you can do is to set height with media Query. That will provide a seamless look.

```
Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
  child: ListView.builder(
    ...
  )
)
```

Comment: I have tried to use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` and that works - however the listview is no longer as responsive to touch interaction