# How to make the whole screen scrollable with ListView.separated

Tags: flutter, listview, layout, widget, flutter-sliver

I have tried using SingleChildScrollView, with setting the child Column with a MainAxisSize.min but was not able to find a WORKING answer. Here is how my widget tree looks like:

```
Scaffold
 Stack
   Column
    Row
    SizedBox
    FutureBuilder
     SizedBox
      SingleChildScrollView
       ListView.separated (physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics())
   Container
```

These are the resources I have looked at:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Flutter/comments/e93ujx/how_to_make_whole_screen_scrollable_with/
- [Flutter ListView Builder scroll whole screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934662/flutter-listview-builder-scroll-whole-screen)
- https://medium.com/@rubensdemelo/flutter-forms-improving-ui-ux-with-singlechildscrollview-7b91aa981475

**Full Code**

```
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1C1C1C),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                getHeading(),
                SizedBox( height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (10/730) ),
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: getContent(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.hasData) {
                      List feedList = snapshot.data;
                      return SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.925,
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: ListView.separated(
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                // code for builder
                              },
                              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return SizedBox( height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (32/730) );
                              },
                              itemCount: feedList.length
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    else {
                      return ErrorScreens().pageNotFound(context, 100, 1, 24);
                    }
                  }
                )
              ],
            ),
            Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8),
                child: BottomNav().primaryBottomNav(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.92, 90, context),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

**EDIT:**  I think some of you didn't understand what I am trying to do. So I have two icons at the top of my screen which act as a heading, and below that is a ListView so when a user scrolls that ListView, I want the entire screen to scroll while this happens.

Comment: ListView is by default scrollable. There is no need to put this inside SingleChildSrollView.

Comment: Wrap your main column with SingleChildScrollView and put NeverScrollablePhysics() in other list

Comment: I did that but, it makes the entire screen fixed and disables scrolling

Comment: did you tried to remove singlechildScrollview,listview is scrollable by default @Calmante c

Comment: so I have two icons at the top of my screen which act as a heading, and below that is a ListView so when a user scrolls that ListView, I want the entire screen to scroll while this happens.

Answer (score -1):

To scroll the whole screen you need to put your column widget inside SingleChildScrollView. So it's going to be something like below..

```
Scaffold
 Stack
   SingleChildScrollView
    Column
     Row
     SizedBox
     FutureBuilder
      SizedBox
        ListView.separated (physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), shrinkWrap:true)
   Container
```

Comment: it isn't scrolling, the entire screen is fixed

Comment: Doesn't work. Did you test this scenario?